# Code blocks runs my code and gives the required output but then says link.exe has stopped working

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc

I ran this code on codeblocks and it gives me the correct output, but then says link.exe has stopped working. I can't figure out why though the code runs fine. I tried to fix all the problems in it because at first it wasn't running at all now that it runs and gives output this weird thing happens. As seen in the code it's a simple assignment where I define a struct of student name and age then it scans the number of student then scans each ones age and name creating a struct for each one by allocating a space in the memory and the links all the structs together then print the list and frees the memory.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuG14.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trLFY.png)

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student {
         char name[50];
         int age;
         struct student* next;
};
struct student * createStudent(char[] ,int);
void createString (struct student *,char []);
struct student * append (struct student *,struct student *);
void print(struct student *);
void freeS(struct student *);

int main (void){
                     int n,stage;
                     char stname[50];
                     struct student * start,*end ,*newp;
                     scanf("%d",&n);
                     for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        scanf("%s %d",stname,&stage);
                        newp=createStudent(stname,stage);
                        if (i==0) {
                            start=newp;
                            end=newp;
                        } else {
                            end = append(end,newp);
                        }
                     }
                     print(start);
                     freeS(start);
}
struct student * createStudent(char n[] ,int x){
          struct student *ptr;
          ptr = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
          ptr->age=x;
          ptr->next= NULL;
          createString(ptr,n);
          return (ptr);
};
void createString(struct student* point,char name[]){

          for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
            point->name[i]=name[i];}
}
struct student * append(struct student * end, struct student * newp){
         end->next=newp;
         return(newp);
};
void freeS(struct student* start){
          struct student * tmp;
            tmp=start;
          while (start!=NULL){
            start=tmp;
            free(start);
            tmp=tmp->next;
          }
}
void print(struct student* start){
          int i = 1;
          while (start!=NULL){
            printf("The Student num%d's name is:%s\n Age is:%d \n",i,start->name,start->age);
            start=start->next;
            i++;
          }
}
```

Comment: I have provided an answer for a problem in your code. It may or may not be the only problem you have. If it doesn't solve all your issues I suggest you run your program in a debugger. At a minimum the debugger can tell you immediately which line of code is crashing the program and it can then be used to step thru the code and examine state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably here in your `freeS` code.

```
tmp=start;
while (start!=NULL){
    start=tmp;
    free(start);
    tmp=tmp->next;
}
```

The last line is dereferencing the memory that has just been freed.

Code should be more like this:

```
while (start != NULL) {
    tmp = start->next;
    free(start);
    start = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly that was it a fixed it and now i understand my mistake thanks alot